# how to add button to yii gridview not the actionColumn a seperate column

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

goodday house please am trying to add an extra column "status" with buttons on each row to yii gridview not under the ActionColumn but a seperate column and also i am trying to pass values into the button, so that the button will display text from my database..
i have tried all have seen is to add it to the ActionColumn please i need ur help

i tried doing something like this but it isnt workin
     // 'Date',

```
[
    'class' => '',
    'template' => '{status}',
    'buttons' => [
        'status' => function ($url) {
          foreach ($reg_course as $reg) {
            return Html::a(
            '<button class="btn btn-info"><?= $reg->student_status?></button>',
            $url, 
            [
                'title' => 'Status',
                'data-pjax' => '0',
            ]
        );
          }

       },
    ],
  ],

  ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...        
[  
'label' => '',  
'format' => 'raw',
'value' => function ($model) {  
    $btn = '<a href="' . Url::home() . 'site/index?id=' . $model->id .'" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Members" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-sm 
    btn-info ">'.$reg->student_status.'</a>';   
    return $btn;   
 },  
],
```

Comment: Thanks So So much.. It worked perfectly.. Wow.. Strugling with this since... Thanks So oo oo ooo much

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate the help, but please i am trying to display a different button colour depending on the value of the status and i have tried different ways but it isnt working

Answer (score 1):

use below code -

```
          [
                'label'=>'Chapters',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value'=>function ($data) {
                 return Html::a('show', '/admin/chapter?subject_id='.$data['id']);
                },
            ],
```

Comment: this will show an anchor link until unless you apply `btn` CSS class bootstrap.